# How to make domain name to point different port not 80 in IIS?

Tags: asp.net, iis, dns, iis-7

I have a domain just bought. Say it is: myowndomain.com. I have added A record with my SERVER IP address. We have two applications on our server. One is with port 3000 and other is with port 3001.

Now I would like to access my applications through this domain. It is working now when I call it by myowndomain.com:3000 and myowndomain.com:3001.

How to setup the system to load port 3000's application if I call myowndomain.com and load 3001's application if I call my.myowndomain.com. [subdomain `my.myowndomain.com` is also added in godaddy]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. I just have to add domain name alias in HTTP binding and save.

Comment: how to add it in `HTTP bindings`? ***In IIS 7***

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to do this by using URL Rewriting. 
Please have a look on below link from iis, here is given complete demo how you can do this:

https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module

you can install ur rewriting from here:

https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

by using this on your applications you can move individual pages also to a specific url. hopefully it will resolve your problem.

Comment: Not sample with URL-Rewrite using a port ?